# Problems with for loop not printing with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Whenever I try to print any statement using a for loop, it does not print using `document.getElementById("").innerHTML=;` - instead it prints using `document.writeln();`

Why?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>For Loop</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>

<script>
var i;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This is Insane";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Show us example code depicting your issue.

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to put something on the page before the page has been loaded.  But, you will need to show us your actual code (in the context of the overall page) for us to know more specifically what is wrong.

Comment: Add code to your question using the "edit" link and format it appropriately.  Do not put multi-line code in comments.

Comment: `<script>` tags should not be after the `</html>` tag.  Put your script right before `</body>`.  Also, it does no good to set the same `.innerHTML` property to "This is Insane" ten times.  Each successive time is just overwriting what you had there previously.  Doing it once will generate the same result.

Comment: Post your code what you have  tried to  execute

Comment: What are you trying to achive? There is no reason for a loop, when you are only changing one variable... Other than that, do as @jfriend00 is suggesting, put your script before the </body>

Comment: You are using id to append the values to the dom it will every time remove the all html and replace new one so you innerhtml is appending in last iteration only

Comment: I edited your question to make your html/JS into a runable code snippet (I didn't change the code), and when clicking the "Run code snippet" button in fact it *does* set the text of the paragraph element... Does this *not* happen in your real project?

Comment: dudes problem solved i have to use     document.getElementById("").innerHTML+="";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 
`document.getElementById("").innerHTML+="";`
now whenever loop will run,data will be incremented.

Comment: try it document.getElementById("").innerHTML+="";

Comment: You Are Legend and life saviour

Comment: yes sir you gave me a perfect solution.. but i don't understand why we are putting + after innerHTML ?

Comment: if you dont put + after innerHTML then whenever loop will be run it will replace the old string and no new string will be added but by adding + sign after innerHTML,whenever the loop will run,data will be increment each time thats all bro